# python aggregation based on relative range of dataframe values

Tags: python, lambda, group-by

I would like to perform a groupby on the key column and sum values based on a plus/minus range of .5 of each row's value.  Below is an example of the data with what my desired output should be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key':[ 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
 'value':[.1, 0.244, 0.373, 0.514, 0.663, 0.786, 0.902, 1.01, 1.151, 1.295, 1.434, 1.541, 1.679, 1.793, 1.94, 2.049, 2.164, 2.284, 2.432, 2.533, 2.68, 2.786, 2.906, 3.008, 3.136],
 'desired_ouput':[1.231, 1.894, 2.68, 3.582, 3.482, 3.238, 2.865, 4.89, 6.431, 9.903, 11.843, 10.833, 11.731, 11.731, 9.002, 7.461, 11.462, 12.093, 17.785, 20.793, 21.765, 21.765, 19.481, 17.049, 14.516]})
```

In the case of the first row, +/1 .5 of the value .1 would be values between -.4 and .6.  This is the sum of .1, .244, .373, and .514 or the desired output for this row of 1.231.

I have tried groupby with lambdas but I have not been able to really find anything that works.  I'd prefer to find panda code to do this rather than embedded if-then statements.  I think I could do this with embedded if-then on my own if I had to.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you've tried and why it wasn't suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, with `.transform`:

```py
N = 0.5

df["desired_output_2"] = df.groupby("key")["value"].transform(
    lambda values: [
        values[(values > (v - N)) & (values < (v + N))].sum() for v in values
    ],
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   key  value  desired_ouput  desired_output_2
0    A  0.100          1.231             1.231
1    A  0.244          1.894             1.894
2    A  0.373          2.680             2.680
3    A  0.514          3.582             3.582
4    A  0.663          3.482             3.482
5    A  0.786          3.238             3.238
6    A  0.902          2.865             2.865
7    B  1.010          4.890             4.890
8    B  1.151          6.431             6.431
9    B  1.295          9.903             9.903
10   B  1.434         11.843             9.903
11   B  1.541         10.833            10.833
12   B  1.679         11.731            11.731
13   B  1.793         11.731            11.731
14   B  1.940          9.002             9.002
15   B  2.049          7.461             7.461
16   C  2.164         11.462             9.413
17   C  2.284         12.093            12.093
18   C  2.432         17.785            17.785
19   C  2.533         20.793            20.793
20   C  2.680         21.765            21.765
21   C  2.786         21.765            19.481
22   C  2.906         19.481            19.481
23   C  3.008         17.049            17.049
24   C  3.136         14.516            14.516
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'value': [0.1, 0.244, 0.373, 0.514, 0.663, 0.786, 0.902, 1.01, 1.151, 1.295, 1.434, 1.541, 1.679, 1.793, 1.94, 2.049, 2.164, 2.284, 2.432, 2.533, 2.68, 2.786, 2.906, 3.008, 3.136]
})

# Custom function to apply
def custom_sum(group):
    return [group[(group['value'] >= row['value'] - 0.5) & (group['value'] <= row['value'] + 0.5)]['value'].sum() for _, row in group.iterrows()]

# Apply the custom function to each group
df['desired_output'] = df.groupby('key').apply(custom_sum).explode().reset_index(drop=True)

df.head()  # Display the first few rows of the DataFrame with the new column
```